# Tangents to an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

I was reading a section on conic sections in a book, and the author writes proofs that show that tangent lines to each of the three non-degenerate types of conic sections intersect at only one point. What's the point of doing this? I'm writing a math research paper for high school, and I'm unsure as to whether to include his proofs or not. Any response will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Looks to me as if your statement is insufficiently quantified, so that for the life of me, I can’t figure out what was being claimed. Could you quote one of these statements exactly?

Comment: What do you mean "intersect at only one point"? The statement is not clear. Obviously the tangent lines to a circle do not intersect at one one point.

Comment: @Maesumi, correct: given a point P not on a conic, there are precisely two tangents from P to the conic (over $\mathbb C$).

Comment: I'm going to the library this afternoon to find the book again, so hopefully I will be able to give you a quote. If it helps, he was using vectors and the property that sum of the distances from one point on the ellipse to the two foci is constant for any point on the ellipse.

Comment: I meant that the tangent line to specific conic intersects that conic at only one point on the conic.

Comment: Perhaps you could have said that each tangent intersects the curve nowhere else on the curve.